# Indices In The Hyperspherical Harmonics

Tags: definition, conventions, spherical-harmonics, special-functions

### Definition

In $d$-dimensional space we have a hyperspherical coordinate system with angles $\theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_{d-2}, \phi$. I am working with the following definition (up to normalisation) of the hyperspherical harmonics in terms of the Gegenbauer polynomials $C$ (Avery & Avery, 2018):
$$
 Y_{\lambda, \mu_1, \mu_2,...}(u_1, u_2,...)\propto e^{im\phi} \prod_{j=1} ^{d-2} C_{\mu_j-\mu_{j+1}}^{\alpha_j+\mu_{j+1}}(\cos{(\theta_j)})(\sin{(\theta_j)})^{\mu_{j+1}},
$$
where the $\lambda$ labels the eigenvalue under the generalised angular momentum operator and the $\mu_i$ the different degenerate eigenstates of $\lambda$ and $2\alpha_j = d − j − 1$. The $u_i=x_i/r$ are hyperradius independent coordinates.

### Question

What is the relationship of $m$ to the $\mu_i$ labelling the degenerate eigenstates? My best guess, trying to extend the notation of the regular spherical harmonics would be that $m=\mu_{d-1}$ since it quantifies the angular momentum associated with $\phi$ which is effectively $\theta_{d-1}$ by given a different symbol to distinguish its larger domain. I can't find any sources or calculations that can confirm this however. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ladder operators are used in the analysis of angular momentum in simple quantum systems. The article [Fano et al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/9905052.pdf) uses a generalisation of ladder operators to explore the properties of hyperspherical harmonics and their expansion in terms of Gegenbauer polynomials.

In particular, Equation (3.7) of the article is essentially the equation you quote. Immediately after Equation 3.7 the authors note that $ |m|\equiv  \mu_{d-1}$.

This is consistent with the suggestion you make in your question.